TV show about pseudo-science and paranormal activity
I'm looking for a TV show that was broadcasted in my youth (late 90s, early 00s) on a Belgian Children's TV Network although it definitely was definitely a show that originates from the English world (American/Australian/...).
The show was about a traveling family, pseudo-science and paranormal activity.
Each episode was introduced by a few facts about the subject or events that could not be (fully) explained by science.
Two episodes I recall quite well:

One about cryonics: a man was frozen postmortem and after he re-awoke found out all his family had died and he was thus alone (and had not much to live for anymore);
One about time traveling where the family received the newspaper of the next day by email.

But since it's a decade ago, it is possible some facts are mixed up (so don't take the plot details too literally).
I know that's not much. I tried to find the name of the show in the on-line archives of the TV network, but that search was unsuccessful :(.

It took awhile for this one to click, but once it did I remembered watching this series (long after it stopped airing) because it'd been compared to the X-Files, like X-Files for the younger generation.
Also because young Jewel Staite was in an episode (Siren). You may know her from Firefly and Stargate Atlantis.

So Weird (1999-2001), originally a Disney Channel show.

A preteen girl travels around the country continually stumbling over
  supernatural occurrences. Without anyone to believe her, she posts
  what she finds on her website entitled "So Weird".  

...

The [series] began with Fiona Phillips on tour with her famous rocker
  mother Molly, brother Jack, a skeptic, bus driver Ned, his wife Irene,
  and their son Clu. Stringing together all of Fi's paranormal
  encounters was her search to communicate with her father, who died
  when she was three years old.

...
...
Your remembered episodes:


One about cryonics: a man was frozen postmortem and after he re-awoke found out all his family
  had died and he was thus alone (and had not much to live for anymore);


"James Garr", 18th episode of the 2nd season: "Fi discovers that Carey's hospital roommate was a cancer patient named James Garr who was cryogenically frozen and has come back to life, but acts distant and emotionless because his soul left his body before he could be revived. Meanwhile, Jack befriends a dying old man who may be the key to James Garr regaining his humanity."


One about time traveling where the family received the newspaper of the next day by email.


"Web Sight", the 2nd episode (ever): "An anonymous emailer sends Fi articles, sound-bits, and videos that predict the future."
...
Opening intros:
Each episode had an opening narration; for example here is the opening narration from "Web Sight":

As long as there's been a tomorrow, people have been obsessed with trying to see it before it becomes today. Nostradamus thought he could
  see the future. Others try looking at tea leaves, crystal balls, Ouija
  boards, even the palms of their hands. For those with the sight, the
  simplest things can be used to fortell what's to come. But even if we
  knew for sure what was going to happen, the question is: what will we
  do about it?


Yes that's it. Many thanks.

The Outer Limits(1995–2002) maybe. In epizode The Refuge there was a man in cryonic suspension.In epizodes Stitch in Time and Tribunal there is a plot about time traveling.

No, that's not it. Although many thanks for the invested effort. Perhaps you should keep this answer such that other people looking for a similar TV show can see this as one of the options.
